# When two createSlice components have reducers with same name then, how to use work with `useDispatch`

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

## Situation:

Let's say there are **two Slice components** defined using redux-toolkit.
Because the **data category is different**, that is why each of them is stored in separate Slice component. Now there are some **reducer functions with same name**, the inside code of those functions are different because the data category is different but the name of reducer is same.

###### So In this case how could we use **`useDispatch`**?

#### Example:

Here is one createSlice Component, I used typescript here:-

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type ImageStructure = {
   id: String;
   originalImage: String;
   croppedImage: String;
   zIndex: Number;
   posX: Number;
   posY: Number;
};
type PayloadStructure = {
   payload: {
      id: String;
      originalImage: String;
      croppedImage: String;
      zIndex: Number;
      posX: Number;
      posY: Number;
   };
};
type RemovePayload = {
   payload: {
      id: String;
   };
};
export const ImgSlice = createSlice({
   name: "image",
   initialState: Array<ImageStructure>(),
   reducers: {
      add: (state, action: PayloadStructure) => {
         state.push(action.payload);
      },
      remove: (state, action: RemovePayload) => {
         let arr = Array<ImageStructure>();
         for (let val in state) {
            if (state[val].id !== action.payload.id) {
               arr.push(state[val]);
            }
         }
         state = arr;
      },
   },
});
export const { add, remove } = ImgSlice.actions;
export default ImgSlice.reducer;
```

And Here is another createSlice component:-

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type textStructure = {
   id: String;
   value: String;
   zIndex: Number;
};
type PayloadStructure = {
   payload: {
      id: String;
      value: String;
      zIndex: Number;
   };
};
type RemovePayload = {
   payload: {
      id: String;
   };
};
export const textSlice = createSlice({
   name: "text",
   initialState: Array<textStructure>(),
   reducers: {
      add: (state, action: PayloadStructure) => {
         state.push(action.payload);
      },
      remove: (state, action: RemovePayload) => {
         let arr = Array<textStructure>();
         for (let val in state) {
            if (state[val].id !== action.payload.id) {
               arr.push(state[val]);
            }
         }
         state = arr;
      },
   },
});
export const { add, remove } = textSlice.actions;
export default textSlice.reducer;
```

So in this above scenario, there could be more types of slices (say, Slice for svg, video, HtmlElement) with same reducer operations.

In this case, how can we use **`useDispatch`** inside our general react component?

### Probable Approach :

One simple solution would be to obviously change the name of the reducers in both the Slice components. But I don't consider this as a scalable solution ( when there are multiple Slice components with same reducer names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename the action creators on import if you get a conflict:

```
import { add as addText } from "./textSlice";
import { add as addImage } from "./imageSlice";

dispatch(addText(""))
dispatch(addImage(img))
```

Or you do it on export:

```
export const { add: addText, remove: removeText } = textSlice.actions;
```